# Problema al imprimir por pantalla luego de leer archivo

Tags: c, linux, consola, txt, printf

Hice el siguiente código en C

```
#include <stdio.h>


typedef struct datos_personales
    {
        char nombre[30];
        char apellido[30];
        int edad;
        char sexo[10];
        char domicilio[30];
        int dni;
    } dpersonales;


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int suma_edades = 0, contador_registros = 0;


    dpersonales registro;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");


    if(fp == NULL){
        perror("Error");
        return 1;
    };


    while ( !feof(fp) ){
        fscanf(fp, "%s%s%i%s%s%i", registro.nombre, registro.apellido, 
        &registro.edad, registro.sexo, registro.domicilio, &registro.dni);
        printf("%s %s %i\n", registro.nombre, registro.apellido, registro.edad);
        suma_edades += registro.edad;
        contador_registros += 1;
    };


printf("El promedio de edades es: %i\n", suma_edades / contador_registros);
printf("La cantidad de registros es: %i\n", contador_registros);




fclose(fp);


return 0;


};
```

Mi archivo txt contiene los siguientes registros:

```
Franco Mariotti 22 M PaseoColon800 12345678
Fernando Fabbiano 21 M PaseoColon100 12345679
Walter Cosmos F 24  PaseoColon200 12345670
Franco Alasino 21 M PaseoColon200 12345670
```

A la hora de ejecutar el código e imprimir por pantalla, me imprime 5 registros (los 4 de mi txt y repite el último). ¿Alguno me podrá decir por qué? Le pase exactamente el mismo código a un amigo, y a el le imprime por pantalla los 4 registros que corresponden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A la hora de ejecutar el código e imprimir por pantalla, me imprime 5 registros (los 4 de mi txt y repite el último). ¿Alguno me podrá decir por qué?

Porque la marca de final de archivo (`eof`) no se lee hasta que has llegado al final del archivo. Vamos a suponer que tienes este archivo:

```
| <-- Inicio del archivo        |            Fin del archivo -> |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| dpersonales 1 | dpersonales 2 | dpersonales 3 | dpersonales 4 |
                                                ^
                                                |
```

Tras leer tres `dpersonales`, el puntero de lectura está exactamente al final del tercero. Cuando inicias la siguiente vuelta del bucle, la condición para seguir se cumple `while (!feof(fp))` y lees un elemento más dejando el puntero al final del cuarto:

```
| <-- Inicio del archivo        |            Fin del archivo -> |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| dpersonales 1 | dpersonales 2 | dpersonales 3 | dpersonales 4 |
                                                                ^
                                                                |
```

El puntero está al final del archivo, pero aún no se reporta final de archivo (EOF), ya que se reporta después de intentar leer, así que la condición para seguir se cumple (`while (!feof(fp))`) e intentas leer un elemento más.

Según la documentación de [`fread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) (traducción mía):

> Si sucede un error, el valor resultante del puntero de lectura del flujo de datos es indeterminado. Si se lee un elemento parcialmente, su valor es indeterminado.

Si al leer sucede un error (como por ejemplo, no haber leído nada porque se acabó el archivo) el valor resultante es indeterminado, en este caso parece que esa indeterminación se traduce en que no lee nada, por lo que el registro aún contiene lo que leyó por última vez, es decir: el último registro.

Answer (score 0):

Falta checkear el output de `fscanf`:

```
while ( !feof(fp) ){
    int numFields = fscanf(fp, "%s%s%i%s%s%i", registro.nombre, registro.apellido, 
    &registro.edad, registro.sexo, registro.domicilio, &registro.dni);

    // Esto asegura que se extrajo el número correcto de campos
    if (numFields != 6) break;

    printf("%s %s %i\n", registro.nombre, registro.apellido, registro.edad);
    suma_edades += registro.edad;
    contador_registros += 1;
};
```

Comment: Hola! Gracias, ahora si me anda, pero no entiendo porque es necesario chequear eso. Como te decia, un amigo corrio el mismo codigo desde su computadora, y la salida era la esperada. Gracias nuevamente,

Comment: Es parte de la especificación de fscanf: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fscanf.3p.html . Quizás la computadora de tu amigo tiene una versión distinta de sistema operativo/kernel?